# Class using NSMutableArray crashing?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsmutablearray

So I am new to Objective-C but not to OOP programming. I am trying to make a class that will add "Squares" to a NSMutableArray but when I wrote the class and ran my app, it crashed. Here is the Squares.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Square.h"

@interface Squares : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *squares; }

-(id) init;
-(void) addSquare: (CGPoint) pos;
-(NSMutableArray *) getSquares;
-(void) update;
-(void) render;

@end
```

And here is the Squares.m file:

> ## import "Squares.h"
>
> @implementation Squares
>
> -(id) init{
>       self = [super init];  if (self != nil) {      squares = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>
> ```
> [self addSquare: CGPointMake(100, 100)];
>       }
>   return self; }
> ```
>
> -(void) addSquare: (CGPoint) pos{
>       Square *square;
>       square = [[Square alloc] init];
>       [square setPosition: pos];
>
> ```
> [squares addObject: square]; }
> ```
>
> -(NSMutableArray *) getSquares{
>       return squares; }
>
> -(void) update{
>       for (int i = 0; i < squares.count; i++){
>           Square *s;
>           s = [squares objectAtIndex: i];
>           [s move];
>
> ```
> } }
> ```
>
> -(void) render{
>       for (int i = 0; i < squares.count; i++){
>           Square *s;
>           s = [squares objectAtIndex: i];
>           [s render];
>
> ```
> } }
> ```
>
> @end

So is this not working just because I have programmed this wrong or not?

Comment: Pffff.... So much errors. E. g., you're confusing pointers with the memory they're point to. You don't need that lonely poor `[Square alloc]`, you just waste your user's RAM...

Comment: Indeed, the `[Square alloc]`s in your `update` and `render` functions do nothing of value. If you've got ARC on, they're just wasted cycles (unless the compiler manages to remove them, but either way, it's a waste). If you don't have it on, you've got a memory leak.

Comment: Ok so I made some changes. The game Runs now, but the square update method isn't working. THe render method is though.

Comment: Never mind. I forgot to add one more line of code to fix it.

Comment: Well, now the code block is unreadable again..

Comment: Another candidate for the Ironic Name Hall of Fame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for (int i = 0; i <= squares.count; i++`

try `for (int i = 0; i < squares.count; i++`

Comment: Ok, I tried that and the other suggestions. The game now runs and the square is rendering, but not moving!?

Comment: Never mind. I forgot to add one more line of code to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `Square *s = [Square alloc];` in the `update` and `render` methods is useless.

As Andrey told you, `for (int i = 0; i <= squares.count; i++)` will count one too far, you should use `<` instead of `<=`.

Better yet just do:

```
-(void) update{
    [squares makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(move)]; }

-(void) render{
    [squares makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(render)]; }
```